# Update Base class values so all derived classes are also updated

Tags: c#, derived-class

I'm hoping to reduce memory requirements on something I'm working for, and ran into a problem with some derived classes.  At the moment I have 4 derived classes that inherit the same base class and override the same method, however the functions in the overridden method are different for each derived class.  this helped clean up a lot of code and made maintenance a LOT easier.  however each derived class has a `long[,] File_Vals` global variable that becomes incredibly large.  here's how the classes are set up.

```csharp
        public class BaseClass {
            public long[,] File_Vals;
            public int Max_rows;
            
            internal void DoWork(){}
        }

        public class FirstDerivedClass : BaseClass
        {
            public DerivedClass(long[,] file_values, int max_rows)
            {
                File_Vals = file_values;
                Max_rows = max_rows
            }
            
            internal new void DoWork()
            {
                // does work stuff
            }
        }

        public class SecondDerivedClass : BaseClass
        ...

        public class Testing
        {
            FirstDerivedClass firstDerived;
            SecondDerivedClass secondDerived;
            ThirdDerivedClass thirdDerived;
            FourthDerivedClass fourthDerived;
            
            public void Setup(long[,] file_values, int max_rows)
            {
                firstDerived = new FirstDerivedClass(file_values, max_rows);
                secondDerived = new SecondDerivedClass(file_values, max_rows);
                thirdDerived = new ThirdDerivedClass(file_values, max_rows);
                fourthDerived = new FourthDerivedClass(file_values, max_rows);
            }
            ...
            
            public void DoStuff(long[,] file_values, int max_rows)
            {
                // updated versions of file_values and max_rows.
            }
        }
```

with this there are 4 sets of `File_values` that have to be updated.  is there a way to only have to update the parent/Base class and thus update the other derived/child classes?  or is there a way that each derived/child classes don't have their own version of the `File_values` object and that there's only one of them that they all access?  right now the `File_values` object can have 12 million rows in it, or more, so memory usage is something that needs to be considered.

Comment: In your code, the 4 derived classes _do_ share the same `long[,]` instance. You are passing the same object to each of them.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay yes, right now that's how they are set up, but this means that in memory there are 5 `long[,]` items at 12 million+ "rows" long.  this takes up a lot of memory and I'm trying to reduce that...

Comment: No, there are not 5 `long[,]` instances. `long[,]` is a reference type, so each derived class is holding a reference to the same object in memory. Unless you are reassigning somewhere that isn't shown.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay oh....okay.  I guess my brain just decided to forget that `long[,]` are reference types....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with this there are 4 sets of File_values that have to be updated

No, in your code in the question there is only one shared instance of `long[,]` (since arrays are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)) and 4 references to it. You can easily check it with next code:

```
Setup(new long[1,1], 1);
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(firstDerived.File_Vals, secondDerived.File_Vals)); // prints True
```

so basically you have `32*4` or `64*4` bits "overhead" depended on platform.

You can make the `File_Vals` field `readonly`, to prevent it from being assigned another value (reference), or, better, get-only property.